# Is there an application to block access to a remote machine (to simulate a disconnection)?

Tags: windows, remote-access, disconnection

Is there some application (with GUI) that enables me to temporarily block access to some remote machine?

My code accesses a remote folder, and I'd like to *simulate disconnection* of couple of seconds to that server.

I don't want to play with shared folder on the remote or start playing with my machine network configuration which is more complicated.

Comment: Lots of such applications around. They 're called firewalls.

Comment: Application of thumb + index finger is pretty effective too.  On the local machine (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your hosts file to point this name to nonexistent IP.

It's here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Manipulating hosts does not simulate a disconnection. Merely alter the DNS and chances are that the already connected sockets won't even notice.